# Xcode - Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) - Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have a problem when I try to compile my program. Do not think it's the code. Create a project so Xcode gives me the main code, it I'm not using, instead create a new file called Triangulo.cpp, I just want to compile this file to see if it works.

This is the text that appears after trying to compile.

```
Ld /Users/oscarespinosa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Poligonos_2D-folpbuxmhfipkuadwfzchugbzton/Build/Products/Debug/Poligonos\ 2D normal x86_64
cd "/Users/oscarespinosa/Documents/Ingenieria Aeronautica/2do Semestre/Programacion Orientada a Objetos/Poligonos 2D"
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/oscarespinosa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Poligonos_2D-folpbuxmhfipkuadwfzchugbzton/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/oscarespinosa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Poligonos_2D-folpbuxmhfipkuadwfzchugbzton/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/oscarespinosa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Poligonos_2D-folpbuxmhfipkuadwfzchugbzton/Build/Intermediates/Poligonos\ 2D.build/Debug/Poligonos\ 2D.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Poligonos\ 2D.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/oscarespinosa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Poligonos_2D-folpbuxmhfipkuadwfzchugbzton/Build/Intermediates/Poligonos\ 2D.build/Debug/Poligonos\ 2D.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Poligonos\ 2D_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/oscarespinosa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Poligonos_2D-folpbuxmhfipkuadwfzchugbzton/Build/Products/Debug/Poligonos\ 2D

duplicate symbol _main in:
/Users/oscarespinosa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Poligonos_2D-folpbuxmhfipkuadwfzchugbzton/Build/Intermediates/Poligonos 2D.build/Debug/Poligonos 2D.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/oscarespinosa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Poligonos_2D-folpbuxmhfipkuadwfzchugbzton/Build/Intermediates/Poligonos 2D.build/Debug/Poligonos 2D.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Triangulo.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the code:

```
//
//  Triangulo.cpp
//  Poligonos 2D
//
//  Created by Oscar Espinosa on 4/6/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 IPN ESIME Ticoman. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int b, h;
float c, a, area, perimetro;

cout << " Calculo de area y perimetro de un triangulo rectangulo" << endl
     << "\n Ingrese el valor de la base: ";
cin >>  b;
cout << "\n Ingrese el valor de la altura: ";
cin >> h;

area = (b*h)/2.00;

c = sqrt(b*b + h*h);
a = c;
perimetro = a+b+c;

cout << "\n El area es: " << area << endl
     << " El perimetro es: " << perimetro;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't really tell what it is without code but it looks like you may be trying to use `#include` improperly. Make sure you're not including the same class multiple times on the same document.

Comment: Just test it in D ++ on Windows and it works, but in Xcode not. :/

Comment: You have duplicate _main symbols.  By default, xcode makes a main.c in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Your project accidentally has a source file which is called "main.c" (or .m or .cpp) which also has a function called "main". Remove that extra file from the project. It's probably starter code that came when you created the project from a template.

Comment: No problem, I've got lots of points anyway. Glad I could help.

Comment: @OscarEspinosa Just accept the answer if it solves your problem.